# basis in $L^{2}[-\pi , \pi]$

Tags: functional-analysis

I know there are many questions regarding this topic but none answers my problem. I am trying to use the fact about the $(e_n)$ being a basis to show that $$E_n = \sqrt\frac{2}{\pi} \sin(nx)$$ for is an orthonormal basis for $L^{2}[0,\pi]$.

Also many answers included the cosine function in the basis, but is there a way to just have the sine function as a basis (i.e. elements of $E_n$)?

[$E_k$ is a basis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wxk0R.png)

Comment: $sin(nx)$ is not a basis in the whole space since $cosx$ is orthogonal to all these functions and clearly not zero.

Comment: The constant function is also not representable in this basis. The set $(E_k)$ where $E_k = \sin(kx/2)$ is a complete basis on this domain, however.

Comment: @Salcio fixed. Domain: $L^{2}[-\pi,\pi]$

Comment: @whpowell96 $E_k = \sqrt\frac{2}{\pi} \sin(kx)$

Comment: Shifting the domain doesn't change the fact that it isn't a basis. Sines only form a complete basis on an interval of length $2L$ with basis elements given by $\sin(n\pi x/L)$

Comment: @whpowell96 let me ask you this: if it is forms a complete orthonormal system in the space, it's a basis then?

Comment: Can $(E_k)$ be a basis if $\langle E_k, 1\rangle = 0$ for all $k$? In other words, why are you so sure this collection is complete?

Comment: @whpowell96 because it says so in a textbook?

Comment: The system $\sin(nx)$ is an orthogonal basis but in $L^2(0,\pi).$

Comment: The image you psoted from your book is a typo. The union of those two sequences is a complete orthogonal basis of $L^2([-\pi,\pi])$, but neither of the sequences individually is complete

Comment: @whpowell96 I figured that out after reading Rysz answer. So how do I use the fact that $e^{inx}$ is a basis to show that $E_k$ is a basis. I don't think I am intended to go through the steps again. (i.e show orthogonality, etc...)

Answer (score 3):

The space $L^2(0,\pi)$ is isometrically isomorphic to the space of odd functions in $L^2(-\pi,\pi),$ by the mapping $f\to 2^{-1/2}\tilde{f}$ where  $\tilde{f}$ is the extension of $f$ to the odd function on $(-\pi,\pi).$ Then $\tilde{f}\perp \cos(nx)$ as $\cos(nx) $ are even functions. Hence $\{\sin (nx)\}$ forms a basis in the space of odd functions in $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$, i.e. in $L^2(0,\pi),$ after restriction to $(0,\pi).$

Comment: Can we write a basis in terms of another basis? Maybe in terms of span?

Comment: I do not quite understand what you mean. Do you have specific orthonormal basis in mind ? In general if we have two orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$ and $\{f_m\}$ then $e_n=\sum_{m=1}^\infty u_{n,m}f_m$ and $U=\{u_{n,m}\}$ is a unitary matrix.

Comment: Thanks. If you want to have a relation between $2^{1/2}\pi^{-1/2}\sin(nx)$ and $2^{1/2}\pi^{-1/2}\cos(mx),$ $\pi^{-1/2},$ in the space $L^2(0,\pi)$ then you need to calculate $\int\limits_0^\pi\sin(nx)\cos(mx)\,dx$ in order to find $u_{n,m}$ from my previous comment. Mind that $n\in \mathbb{N}$ while $m\in \mathbb{N}\cup{0}.$