# Showing that $\{\sqrt{2}\sin(\pi n x): n\in\mathbb{N}_0\}$ is an orthonormal basis for the space $L^2([0,1])$ given that $e^{2\pi il x}$ forms a basis

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces, fourier-series, lp-spaces, harmonic-analysis

Define $S:= \{\sqrt{2}\sin(\pi n x): n\in\mathbb{N}_0\}$ where $N_0 = \{0,1,2,\dots\}$. I want to show that $S$ is an orthonormal basis for the space $L^2([0,1])$ when it is know that the set $\tilde{S}:= \{e^{2\pi il x}:l\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ forms an ONB for $L^2([0,1])$. I have been given a hint to construct a suitable isomorphism between $S$ and $\tilde{S}$, but I am not really sure how. I initially thought of mapping each $\sqrt{2}\sin(\pi n x)$ to some $e^{2\pi il x}$ by dividing with $\sqrt{2}$, multiplying the argument $x$ by two and introducing a sign depending on parity of $n$, i.e.

$$\sqrt{2}\sin(\pi n x)) \mapsto \sin(2\pi f(n)x + \pi/2) + i\sin(2\pi f(n)x)$$

where $f$ is a bijection from $\mathbb{N}_0$ to $\mathbb{Z}$. Under this mapping inner product should be preserved by orthogonality of the sines. My problem is that I don't know how to extend this map to the whole space $L^2([0,1])$.

How close is this construction to a proper solution and is there an easier way to achieve the claim?

Comment: This can't be a basis, since the value is $0$ at $x=0$ for all $n.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Hmm, true. But why is this a problem?

Comment: Because there are $f\in L^2[0,1]$ with $f$ with $f(0)=1,$ and you can't approximate $f$ with this prospective basis? Or at least, it seems unlikely you can.

Comment: As a side note, when $n=0,$ the function is zero everywhere, and a zero function cannot be a basis element, much less an orthonormal basis element.

Comment: If we add $\cos(\pi n x)$, we get basis of $L^2([-1, 1])$. And if we continue $f$ to $[-1, 1]$ by rule $f(-x) = -f(x)$, we will get zero coefficients for $\cos$ terms. So it is indeed basis. But I don't know how to show this from knowledge that $\tilde{S}$ is a basis, without appeal to standard result about basis of $L^2([-1, 1])$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: The point $x=0$ is of Lebesgue measure zero and inconsequential for $L_2$ approximations.

Comment: Related question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4678705/basis-in-l2-pi-pi/4678727#4678727

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one extends any function $f\in L_p[0,1]$  to a function $f_o$ on $[-1,1]$  so that $f_o=(-x)=-f(x)$ for $0\leq x\leq 1$, then the extension $f_o$ is an odd function and $f_o\in L_p(-1,1)$ since
$$\|f_o\|_{L_p[-1,1]}=2^{1/p}\|f\|_{L_p[0,1]}$$

Now,for the case $p=2$. The Fourier series (in terms of $f_o$ as an element of $L_2[-1,1]$) contains only sine terms ($f_o$ being odd). This will show that $\{S_n(x)=\sin(\pi n x):n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is indeed an orthogonal basis for $L^2[0,1]$.

The linear map such that $S_n\mapsto \frac{e_n-e_{-n}}{i\sqrt{2}}\in L_2[-1,1]$, where $e_n(x)=e^{\pi n ix}$,$n\in\mathbb{N}$ defines the  isometry the OP is  looking for.

Similar approach can be used to show that $\{C_n(x)=\cos(\pi n x): n\in\mathbb{Z}_+\}$
is an orthogonal basis for $L_2[0,1]$. The extension of function $f$ on $[0,1]$ to a function $f_e$ on $[-1,1]$  is now set to be $f_e(-x)=f(x)$ for all $0\leq x\leq 1$.

Comment: If the following argument is correct, I have a question: For $I_1=[0,1],I_2=[-1,1]$, i.) we can extend any $f\in L^2(I_1)$ to $L^2(I_2)$ by $\tilde{f}(x)=f(x),0<= x<=1$ and $\tilde{f}(x) = -f(x),-1<= x<0$, ii.) as such $\tilde{f}$ is an odd function, its Fourier series can contain only sine terms. Hence any extended function can be represented by elements of $S$, showing that $S$ is an ONB for $L^2(I_1)$?

If this is the argument, does it then boil down to us not losing anything by considering extensions of functions? I.e. why can/should we jump from functions over $I_1$ to those over $I_2$?

Comment: @EpsilonAway: This is related to the fact that you can write any real function as the sum of an odd and and even function. Like I said in my comment, extending $f$ to get even functions would give you another complete orthogonal basis for $L_2([0,1]$. The argument I laid down in my posting works because $\|f_{odd}\|_{L_2(I_2)}=\sqrt{2}\|f\|_{L_2(I_1)}$ (similar for $f_{odd}$ replace by $f_{even}$.

Comment: @EpsilonAway: Also notice that $\int^1_{-1}\sin(n\pi x)f_0(x)\,dx=2\int^1_0\sin(n\pi x) f(x)\,dx$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, one last thing I would like to ask is that is the final step then to just restrict our oddly extended function $f$ back to the interval $[0,1]$, with the sine series representation?

Comment: @EpsilonAway: my intension was to map $L_2[0,1]$ into $L_2[-1,1]$. The map I defined is an isometric embedding of *sine series* onto the space of odd functions in $L_2[-1,1]$.